# Deleting a method from Visual Studio properties window

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

The "Events", "Messages" and "Overrides" tabs in the Properties Window can be used to add new methods to a class as well as to remove them. However, when you select to "Delete" a method, it comments the method code instead of deleting it.

I know this is for safety issues, but I almost never need the commented code and end up having to delete it manually. This is even more annoying in MFC, when I have to delete the method declaration, the method implementation and the entry on the message map which are usually on different places.

Is there an option to simply delete the method code instead of just commenting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way of doing this, especially in C++ where there are too many places that directly or indirectly exist as part of the method declaration.

Comment: OK, I'll accept this as long as no one comes up with some way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Even if there was an option for this, I don't think I'd trust it to do the right thing.